# Microsoft-Cognitive Text to Text

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I have been trying to use the Microsoft MT API for memoQ. At first, it worked. I tried again today but client ID and secret appear to be incorrect when I check the login data in memoQ Microsoft MT API. Would you be able to look into it? Thanks, Daniela

Answer (score 0):

You need the latest version of MemoQ, and within the Machine Translation plugins list you will find 2 choices - "Microsoft MT plugin (legacy)" and "Microsoft MT plugin".  You will want the second one - "Microsoft MT plugin" - and in the options dialog for that you will be prompted for a Subscription key where you will enter the API account key from your Azure Cognitive Services Translator account.

Client ID and Client Secret are no longer used.